# merging arrays with foreach and losing string value

Tags: php, arrays

Quick question: what causes me to lose a sting value when combining 2 arrays with for each loops?

```
Array1: 

array (size=971)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 2
      'YrNro' => int 2
      1 => string 'H�n OY' (length=6)
      'YrNimi' => string 'H�n OY' (length=6)

Array2:

  0 => 
    array (size=16)
      0 => int 8
      'AineistoID' => int 8
      1 => int 2
      'AsiakasID' => int 2
      2 => int 1
      'TilaID' => int 1
      3 => int 1
      'OsastoID' => int 1
      4 => int 1
      'Kohdekk' => int 1
      5 => int 2014
      'Kohdevuosi' => int 2014
      6 => string 'SADF' (length=4)
      'Kuvaus' => string 'SADF' (length=4)
      7 => string 'Apr 24 2014 01:01:07:053PM' (length=26)
      'Vastaanotettu' => string 'Apr 24 2014 01:01:07:053PM' (length=26)


foreach($tilat as $line_r1)
{
    foreach($yrityslista as $line_r2)
    {
        if($line_r1[1] == $line_r2[0])
        {
            $line = $line_r1;
        $line[] = $line_r2[1];
        //var_dump($line_r2);
        $dbquery_combination[] = $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Now on the result `$dbquery_combination[]`, all the cells where the value should be `$dbquery_combination[8] = string 'H�n OY'` the value is string ' ', (empty string); What happens to the original value?

Could it be because of the umlauts and if it is what should I do? I have tried typecasting and switching the result to utf8 format.

Many thanks.

Comment: � the character for \ufffd is problematic. Do a google on "problems with  \ufffd"

Comment: I think its the browser when the character gets dumped. If it is so, you could replace the character before passing to the browser  (i.e. if it won't hinder your application)

Comment: whitch charset are you using?

Comment: So I assume I should do something like preg_grep and preg_replace.